# How to get the fragment part of an URL from libcurl?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I get redirected to a page with address like `http://example.com#foo=bar`. I want to get `foo=bar` part of it. The whole thing would be ok too.

I found this thing:

```
char * url;
curl_easy_getinfo(myHandle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);
```

I don't know english well to find information myself. Every time I want to find it, I find information on getting the page into string variable.

Code:

```
std::string readBuffer;
curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
CURL * myHandle;
CURLcode result;
myHandle = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "coo.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "coo.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.ru/#q=stack");
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
result = curl_easy_perform(myHandle);
char * ch_cur_url;
result = curl_easy_getinfo(myHandle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL,
        &ch_cur_url);
printf("%s\n", ch_cur_url);
```

Outputs `https://www.google.ru/`

When I wanted `https://www.google.ru/#q=stack`

Comment: You may find this answer useful: [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/1413395)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, maybe. I know how to split strings. I just can't get the whole string. Is not that clear enough? How to make it clearer?

Comment: So what's the actual result for `char * url;`?? Yes, you need to make your question clearer a lot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what else? Maybe I had to ask that before.

Comment: _'what else?'_ Provide appropriate snippets of code you have tried, what you have expected to be their outcome, and what you actually got. In other words: Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Better, yes. `curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);` looks suspicious, does this even compile? From the [docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html): _"Strings passed to libcurl as `char *` arguments"_ As for the `curl_easy_getinfo()` I can't actually spot how to get the fully requested URL.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `&readBuffer` compiles all right. Can I get the fully requested URL from Haders?

Comment: _'compiles all right'_ Suspect though! A `std::string*` isn't the same thing as a `char *`! _'Can I get the fully requested URL from Haders?'_ Probably, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL removes the "fragment identifier" from the URL before making a request, as per the bug reports ([1](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2009-04/0252.html), [2](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1159/)). See also [this patch](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2010-01/0027.html). Thus the "fragment identifier" is not available as part of the `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`.

If the "fragment identifier" is returned as part of a redirect (e.g. the `Location` HTTP header) and you can't get it any other way, then you may use the debug modes to peek on the communications between the cURL and the servers and extract the "fragment identifier" yourself. To that end you'll need to setup either `CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION` or `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`.

P.S. A bit of advise: Googling the relevant information was very easy. First thing I did was to learn the "official" name of the `#foo=bar`. To get it I visited Wikipedia at [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url) and was brought to [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). After that, Googling with the "curl fragment" netted the relevant parts. If you're looking for something, learn it's proper name.

Comment: After a nit of googling, it seems to me that my question is not clear. It seems that fragment from `https://www.google.ru/#q=stack` will be trimmed. Is that so?

Comment: The "fragment identifier" is trimmed, yes. Check the wikipedia article, the browser should never send the fragment identifier to the server and so it's not a part of the effective URL.